# TRIM string concated values

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that works just fine but the result comes with trailing and leading quotes. This is how:

```
SELECT 
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',1), ',', -1) as first_col,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',2), ',', -1) as second_col,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',3), ',', -1) as third_col,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',4), ',', -1) as fourth_col

FROM (
    select 
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) as concat_values
    FROM my_table t1
    GROUP BY (uid) 

    ) t;
```

The result is something like:

```
 Column1             Column2                  Column3       

["Result_1"]        ["Result_2"]             ["Result_3"]
```

I want to TRIM both the parentheses([]) and the quotes (" ") so that the result displays as 'Result_1'. Have tried using `TRIM(BOTH)` but I get a syntax error.

How best do I trim it?

Comment: These seem like JSON strings.  You could parse them as JSON in PHP (or whatever language you are using).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
    $str = '["Result_1"]';
    echo trim($str, '"');

    $str = '["Result_1"]';
    echo trim($str, '[');

    $str = '["Result_1"]';
    echo trim($str, ']');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply bluto but I want to trim it in the same mysql query text (using the select statement)

Comment: try `REPLACE( COLNAME,'"','')` in query

Answer (score 1):

This can solve your problem within mysql

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM '["test"]')))
```

What I prefer is to trim the strings within your application side due to performance considerations.

### Edit

Here is how you can add trim to your sql

```
SELECT 
    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',1), ',', -1))))  AS first_col,
    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',2), ',', -1))))  AS second_col,
    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',3), ',', -1))))  AS third_col,
    TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(concat_values, ',',4), ',', -1))))  AS fourth_col
FROM (
select 
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) as concat_values
FROM my_table t1
GROUP BY (uid) 

) t;
```

Comment: ok.. would you mind using it in the mysql query I gave above please? I just want to see how it fits in there. thanks